# HTML/css Repeat backround image twice on print

Tags: html, css

I want to make the background image to repeat exactly 2 times , once in every page on print format on chrome.There are always 2 pages and the second does not go all the way down. I also use dynamic data from php.I am currently using this code and the second print of the image starts at first page and not showing in the second  :

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    body
    {
        background-image:url(image.png);
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        background-position: right top;
        width:auto; 
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution of this problem in CSS. Though you can try-out this trick:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    body{
        background-image:url('red.png'),url('red.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: 0px top, 250px top;
    }
</style>
```

You need to add your background exactly as much times you want it to repeat. You can change its position accordingly.

Also `width:auto;` is redundant as `auto` is the default value of `width` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it works just like mine. The second repeat ( or the second photo on yours code )  starts at the first page  and stops  right there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code. I hope it will surely solve your problem.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            #watermark{
                position: fixed;
                background-image:url('red.png');
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position: top center;
                width: 100%;
                height: 20%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="watermark"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here we using empty `<div>` as background container and set its `position: fixed` relative to the browser. Now we don't need to load `background-image` multiple times as well. `background-repeat:no-repeat` is necessary if you want it to show only once. Finally, you can adjust `width`, `height` and `background-position` properties according to your need.

Here is the end-result:
[image]

Comment: i am sorry but it is the same as the other. Thanks for your time tho

Comment: Do you have more than 2 pages and you want to show background on only 2 particular pages?

Comment: I added the end-result. Compare it with yours. To make multiple pages I just added some random text and whole bunch of `<br>` repeatedly.

Comment: This code does not work for me. Still not printing after the start of the second page. I used these options and it actually worked (it is a mix from your two aswers) :
       background-image:url('template.png'),url('template.png');
                background-repeat:repeat;
                background-position: top center;
    background-size:100% 1030px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 200%;

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: welcome :) Now I understand I misunderstood your question.

First I thought you want to print background 2 times on 1st page and not after that. Next I thought you want to print one img per page, coz you said:
{{ The second repeat ( or the second photo on yours code ) starts at the first page and stops right there.}}

 Your code (with alterations as per img size) prints 2 full-page-width wide images per page. I think if you give some picture it would be much helpful to understand. But what matters is that your problem solved. Surely your brain also enjoys this puzzle like mine :) Cheers.

Comment: {{ There are always 2 pages and the second does not go all the way down.}} - this line is redundant and confusing because we talking about background image and suddenly starts talking about no of pages. {{  I also use dynamic data from php. }} - It is also unnecessary as problem is about CSS also you havn't shared any PHP.